# SQL QUERY for showing top 10 products by unit volume, AdventureWorks database

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I am currently using the AdventureWorks database and trying to show top 10 products by unit volume. I would like it to look like my top 10 sales summary. Any thoughts on a quick edit to just have it show top 10 products by unit volume for the same 2013 year?

This is what I used for top 10 sales.

```
SELECT TOP 10
     sod.ProductID
    ,prd.Name
    ,SUM(LineTotal) AS SumOfSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
    ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
JOIN Production.Product prd
    ON prd.ProductID  = sod.ProductID
WHERE SOH.OrderDate > '01/01/2013' AND SOH.OrderDate < '12/31/2013'
GROUP BY sod.ProductID, prd.Name
--HAVING SUM(LineTotal) >= 2000000
ORDER BY SUM(LineTotal) DESC
```

Comment: Why skip new year's day and new year's eve? Column OrderDate data type?

Comment: So I should have it listed as 12/31/2012 / 1/1/2014 then right?

Comment: Or use `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: >= seems like the easier fix, thanks so much for catching that.

Comment: Also you should use an unambiguous date format such as `'20130101'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10
 sod.ProductID
,prd.Name
,SUM(OrderQty) AS SumOfSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
JOIN Production.Product prd 
ON prd.ProductID  = sod.ProductID
WHERE SOH.OrderDate > '01/01/2013' AND SOH.OrderDate < '12/31/2013'
GROUP BY sod.ProductID, prd.Name

ORDER BY SUM(OrderQty) DESC
```

This is what I came up with I just switched LineTotal and Order QTY

Comment: And again - you ignore rows for Jan 1 and Dec 31 so your totals are incorrect if there are rows for either date. In general, it is better to use an inclusive lower boundary (Jan 1 2013) and an exclusive upper boundary (e.g., Jan 1 2014) to avoid precision issues (just in case the column is datetime or similar).

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I copy/pasted the older snippet